# Error with WCF activation

Tags: wcf

As you will notice the [namespace|app name] is not the same from the error to what I used in the config. The files were renamed in the project and I cannot see where it is getting the default service1 name from. I have rebuilt the project and re-published. Do you see anything I may be missing?

> Error: The type 'EncServWeb.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

```
web.config
serviceActivations  
        add service="EncServWeb.Serv" relativeAddress="~/Serv.svc"
serviceActivations
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Michael. It really didn't like the xml part at all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've edited the .svc file and the web config?

Not just the web config, right? If you havent changed the contents of your .svc file, this is where the error is...

If this isnt the cause, and you host in IIS... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2006/08/10/wcf-service-nesting-in-iis.aspx

Comment: When you say edited the .svc file you mean the file name right - if so then yes. All the files in solution where changed and all files in the project folder are the same. No files I can see say Service1 on them???

Answer (score 0):

In this video I found where I had to reassign the service name from the default to the newly named one in the app.config file. [Create your first WCF Service](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Service/). Hope this helps someone else!